# Spring bean property define

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two class A and B . A is parent and B is child class.
am calling the class B methods.but class b accessing the methods of A.and i want to set a property in class A. So defined the property like

```
<bean name="b" class="com.dao.B" parent="parent">
    <property name="utility" ref="utility"/>
</bean>


<bean class="com.dao.A" id="parent">
     <property name="utility" ref="utility"/>
</bean>
```

and in the class A have a property named utility and with a setter...
when i try to get the instance i got null...
can u help me to set that

Comment: Are you running this program as standalone or inside some container (like tomcat) ?

Answer (score 0):

As A has a public setter of field utility then you can directly set property of object in class A from B like.

```
<bean name="b" class="com.dao.B">
    <property name="utility" ref="utility"/>
</bean>
```

here utility is in class A with public setter and we are set value in B bean.

Comment: intially i tried like this ..but still i got null.from class C am calling like B.getHello() where getHello is a method of Class A..

Comment: @Rekha have to tried this.. If the same problem can you please share exact code of class and mapping so that we can actually see the exact situation

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `parent` attribute, try this

```
<bean id="b" class="com.dao.B" >
    <property name="utility" ref="utility"/>
</bean>

<bean id="a" class="com.dao.A">
     <property name="utility" ref="utility"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is A a parent (in spring means) of B?
If not, just remove parent="parent" and id="parent" and you will be fine.
Read spring docs about abstract beans definition and use of parent.